# Add info window to the destination marker from a route

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to add an info window to the final destination of a route. I searched the net but found that to add an info window I must create a new object.
Note that I have a static starting point and the end point is dynamically taken it's latitude/longitude from database. So all I want to have is an info window with custom text appeared when the B icon, the end point is clicked.

This example is pretty similar with my situation: http://jsfiddle.net/gHK7s/2/

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true
});
```

Hope you guys can help me out with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mp3ca7j/) based on the one you post, but with the modifications to add a marker at the end of the route.

As stated in the other answer, one of the modifications needed is to add the option to suppress the route markers

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ draggable: true, suppressMarkers: true });
```

Then you have to add the marker at the end, you can use these two functions:

```
function showDestinationMarker(directionResult) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: directionResult.routes[0].legs[0].end_location,
      map: map
    });
    attachMarkerText(marker, "The end.");
    markerArray[0] = marker;
}

function attachMarkerText(marker, text) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    // Open an info window when the marker is clicked on,
    // containing the text of the step.
    stepDisplay.setContent(text);
    stepDisplay.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

Comment: I focused on this to answer "all I want to have is an info window with custom text appeared when the B icon, the end point is clicked", could be that my answer isn't so clear

Comment: This adds a marker to each route step and attaches an infoWindow to  each of them. This doesn't add an infoWindow/Marker to the start or end point.

Comment: `myRoute.steps` contains only the start location and the next steps but **not** the end location. Further to that, adding your own marker at the end location can be easily achieved without that loop (the Service response contains the `end_location`) but **first** you have to use `suppressMarkers` as stated in my answer, otherwise you'll end up with 2 markers at the end location. Got it?

Comment: @MrUpsidown Updated the answer, thanks for the "Got it?", it make me think.., now my answer looks better

Comment: Yes! That works now ;-) +1 for the complete answer and example. @user3759547 If you need the same markers, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746740/google-map-icons-with-visualrefresh but as a **side node**: this is **undocumented** and the [Charts / infographics API](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons) has been deprecated since over 2 years... so use them at your own risks!

Comment: Hi,
sorry for my very late reply but health problems occurred suddenly.
Hopefully I am ok now, will look at your suggestions and customize them to my needs. Thank you guys !

Answer (score 1):

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22639746/1238965

The key is to use `suppressMarkers` in the DirectionsRenderer:

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true
});
```

Then add your own [markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) at the start and destination, and your custom [infoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) at the destination.