# Default markers at the start and end of a poly-line places above my custom markers in Google maps JavaScript/Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In `Vue2` I am trying to change the google maps default marker to a custom Image. created custom markers showing on the map but, when I draw the poly-line between them default red color markers get place above the custom marker. I couldn't hide or replace the default markers.

suggested answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639178/custom-and-waypoint-markers-in-google-maps) is for way-points marker not start and end of a poly-line.

I uses `vue2-google-maps` package.

this is a screenshot of the map

[image]

this is the template

```
<template>
  <div>
    <GmapMap
      :center="center"
      :zoom="zoom"
      map-type-id="roadmap"
      style="width: 100%; height: 300px"
      ref="map"
      >
      <GmapMarker
        v-for="(m, index) in markers"
        :key="index"
        :ref="`marker${index}`"
        :position="m.position"
        :clickable="true"
        :icon="m.icon"
      />
      <DirectionsRenderer
       v-if='start!=null'
      travelMode="DRIVING"
      :origin="origin"
      :destination="destionation"/>
    </GmapMap>
  </div>
</template>
```

and this is the script part

```
<script>
import DirectionsRenderer from './DirectionsRenderer.js'
export default{
  components: {DirectionsRenderer},
  data:()=>({
    markers:[],
    center:{lat:49.2831066, lng:-123.1031387},
    zoom:10,
    start:null,
    end:null,
  }),
 
  computed: {
    origin() {
      if (!this.start) return null;
      return { query: this.start };
    },
    destionation() {
      if (!this.end) return null;
      return { query: this.end };
    }
  },
  methods:{
    drawRoute(){
      this.start = this.order.from.formatted_address;
      this.end = this.order.to.formatted_address;
    },
    setBounds(){
      const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds()
        for (let m of this.markers) {
          bounds.extend(m.position)
        }
        this.$refs.map.fitBounds(bounds)
    },
    init(){
      this.markers=[
        {
          position: {lat:49.2831066 ,lng:-123.1031387},
          icon: 
          { 
            url: '/images/icons/pickup.png',
            size: {width: 60, height: 60, f: 'px', b: 'px',},
            scaledSize: {width: 20, height: 20, f: 'px', b: 'px',},
          }
        },
        {
          position: {lat:49.2544622,lng:-123.1053708},
          icon:{ 
            url: '/images/icons/destination.png',
            size: {width: 60, height: 60, f: 'px', b: 'px',},
            scaledSize: {width: 20, height: 20, f: 'px', b: 'px',},
          }
        }
      ];
      
    }
   this.setBounds();
  },
  created(){
    this.init();
  }
}
</script>
```

and this is `DirectionsRenderer.js` script

```
import { MapElementFactory } from "vue2-google-maps";

export default MapElementFactory({
    name: "directionsRenderer",

    ctr() {
        return google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    },

    events: [],

    mappedProps: {},

    props: {
        origin: { type: Object },
        destination: { type: Object },
        travelMode: { type: String }
    },

    afterCreate(directionsRenderer) {
        let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        this.$watch(
            () => [this.origin, this.destination, this.travelMode],
            () => {
                let { origin, destination, travelMode } = this;
                if (!origin || !destination || !travelMode) return;

                directionsService.route(
                    {
                        origin,
                        destination,
                        travelMode
                    },
                    (response, status) => {
                        if (status !== "OK") return;
                        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
});
```

`directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);` in bellow snipet draw a line with default markers at the beginning and end of the line.

```
directionsService.route(
                    {
                        origin,
                        destination,
                        travelMode
                    },
                    (response, status) => {
                        if (status !== "OK") return;
                        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
                    }
                );
```

any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Duplicate of [Custom and waypoint markers in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639178/custom-and-waypoint-markers-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, If anyone having the same problem I share my solution here.

In the bellow code

```
directionsService.route(
                    {
                        origin,
                        destination,
                        travelMode
                    },
                    (response, status) => {
                        if (status !== "OK") return;
                        //directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
                    }
                );
```

on `directionService.route()` callback instead of `directionRenderer.setDirections(response)` loop through `overview_path` and push all the cordinates into `path`.

```
var vm = this;
directionsService.route(request,function(result,status){
                if(status =='OK'){
                  const route = result.routes[0];
                  route.overview_path.forEach(e=>{
                      var latlng = {
                        lat: e.lat(),
                        lng: e.lng()
                      };
                      vm.path.push(latlng);
                  })
                }
            });
```

Comment: The overview path, as its name says is an overview, simplified path. Not the way to go.